# Euclidean distance (cosine) between two random positive unit vectors in high dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, machine-learning

I found out that the largest possible euclidean distance (which is the cosine) between two random positive unit vectors decreases as the dimension of vector increases and approximates 0.71. This was done by a simulation where I randomly sample unit vectors and compute the maximal pair-wise Euclidean distance. I found the value 0.71 intriguing. It's as if the maximal angle between all vectors is 45 degrees (cosine(45) ≈ 0.71), which is half of 90 degrees related to the constraint of having only positive elements.

Why is that? I sense there is an intuitive explanation to this which can be generalized to other cases, e.g. without the positive vector constraints.

You can use the following code to reproduce the simulation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity, euclidean_distances
matrices = [Normalizer(norm = 'l2').fit_transform(np.random.rand(1000, N)) for N in range(2,10000, 100)]
res = [euclidean_distances(matrix, matrix).max() for matrix in matrices]
plt.plot(range(len(res)),res)
```

[plot of the max euclidean distance with different dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnhBn.png)

Comment: Sometimes known as “the curse of high dimensionality.” See https://scibib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf and many other discussions of this.

Comment: Your code apparently makes use of random samples, but the text doesn't mention that random aspect. As I see it, large distances don't become impossible, they just become car less probable. After all, a high-dimensional space includes a subspace of lower dimension so the high distance vector pairs are still possible. I suggest you edit your text to reflect this.

Comment: @MvG  Thanks, I have edited the question. I understand your reasoning. Yet I don't get where the 0.71 comes from and the mathematics behind this max bound.